# Рендер после синхронизации двух коллекций с сервером

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, frontend

Использую BackboneJS.
Необходимо рендерить представление когда данные (в виде двух коллекций) синхронизированы с сервером.
Но в моем коде рендер будет вызван дважды: при 'sync' каждой коллекции.
Как бы задать слушателя события синхронизации с сервером одновременно двух коллекций? Т. е. рендерить когда обе коллекции синхронизированы, а не одна.

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: fucntion(options) {
        this.coll1 = options.coll1;
        this.coll2 = options.coll2;
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var childView = new ChildView({
            coll1: this.coll1,
            coll2: this.coll2
        });
        ....
});

var ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(options) {
            this.listenTo(this.options.coll1, 'sync', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this.options.coll2, 'sync', this.render);   
        }
        ....
});
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что обе коллекции должны быть отрисованы в рамках одного представления? Или же это представление можно как-то разделить?

Comment: В представлении два select-а. Для каждого своя коллекция со значениями option.

Answer (score 1):

Через прослушку никак. Самое простое это сделать так. Набросаю небольшой кусок кода.

```js
var collection1, collection2,
    promise1, promise2;

collection1 = new Backbone.Collection();
collection2 = new Backbone.Collection();


promise1 = collection1.fetch();
promise2 = collection2.fetch();

Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
  .then(function() {
    // Здесь вызом метода рендер вьюхи
  });
```